# Double level of sliding DIV on Mouse Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create a similar effect as in the site http://tracelytics.github.io/pageguide/ where when you hover the mouse on the "Page guide" icon present in left side of screen, it extends further and show another level of information along with it.

How can I get this effect? I also want to use the same icon.

I don't know where to start on this. Any sample fiddle or plugin will help me. Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to use the Pageguide plugin instead of creating your own?

Comment: I am not going to use that plugin. I am trying to create the effect as that plugin does.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/SqjfT/

Here's a very simple implementation I created that simulates what you see in that plugin.

```
var old;
$(".hover").hover(
function(){
    old = $(this).css("right");
    $(this).animate({right:"0"},100);  
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({right:old},100);  
}
)
```

Comment: How can I add the image as in the site I shared?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with css and only jquery to open the modal. This post first will have the css only (I did not put the image, but if you have some css knowledge you can add your own image).

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/9sH3v/

```
body {
 overflow: hidden;
}
#page_tab {
 background: #ccc;
 width: 150px;
 height: 50px;
 position: absolute;
 right: -5em;
 transition: all .5s ease;    
}
#page_tab:hover {
 right: 0;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}

<div id="page_tab"></div>
```

HERE IS THE JQUERY

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/9sH3v/1/

```
$('#page_tab').click(function () {
function buildFrame() {
    if ($('#mid').length > 0) {} else {
        $('body').append("<div id='mid'></div>");
        $('#mid').css({
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            position: "absolute",
            top: "0",
                "backgroundColor": "rgba(51, 51, 51, .5)"

        });
    }
    if ($('#info').length > 0) {} else {
        $('#mid').append("<div id='info'></div>");
        $('#info').css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: "35%",
            left: "35%",
            fontSize: "6em",
            color: "#fff"
        });
    }
}
buildFrame();
$('#info').empty().append("YOUR CONTENT");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am learning CSS and jquery.. I can understand a little of this code. How can I add image above text as in the link I shared? Thanks again.

Comment: You would want to add it as a background that way you can position it above your text, you can do it as a img but i typically like to do it as a background.

Comment: The background url has size 50px, position which positions it within the tab. Cursor: pointer just makes it so people get the idea that they click it.

Comment: This looks almost similar as I require. Thanks again. I want to show a text too below the image when in normal position. When I tried, both text and image gets overlapped. Sorry for the trouble on this.

Answer (score 0):

This effect has been achieved with CSS3 animations. You must declare the transition property in your CSS, here you have an example code:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
```

And here you have an example in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/Zm9uc/

Comment: How can I add the image as in the site I shared?

Comment: With css too. Use the background-image property. I updated de jsfiddle with the same icon that page uses: http://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/Zm9uc/3/

Comment: When I use a text along with the image, they both get overlayed. How do make it in new line in CSS?

Comment: Post an jsfiddle to understand you.

Answer (score 0):

I may be slow to make a fiddle but... her ya go. You have to use css `transitions` like so

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
```

. I made a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Davidicus/BpAL5/

Comment: This looks close what I am looking for. Thanks. How can I add the image as in the site I shared?

Comment: There are a couple ways but I used a pseudo element to put a red box. you can check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Davidicus/BpAL5/  for the markup and styling. Just Change the "red" for an image path that you have and you will be good to go. If my answer helped can you mark it as correct?